# List of US states by area, how do I read file and choose the largest state based on user's 3 inputs?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I want to read a file that has all the states in order by land area.  I want the user to input 3 states, and the program determines the largest state of the three.  How do I go about doing this.

Comment: You don't say anything about where you see the problems. You have to open a file, read the contents into some data structure. Then ask the user for input 3 times. Finally compare some values and display a result. If you know how to do *any* of this, just start there and add the rest later. A first prototype could be `cout << "The largest state is Texas."`, which at least solves one test case. :-)

Comment: @BoPersson Alaska is more than twice the size of Texas.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you need to do is read your file(states are already sorted area wise).Fill an array from that file in correct order and then do a linear search to find the where state given in input is order wise.Then store them in in another array and compare their value.Then output the element with highest area.

something like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()  {
    string var,states[50],input[3];
    int count=0,arr[3];
    ifstream file;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        getline(cin,input[i]);
}
// search area wise from file
file.open(/*location of the .txt file*/);
while(getline(file,var)) {
    states[count] = var;
    count++;
}
// do a linear search
for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<50;j++) {
        if(states[j] == input[i])
            arr[i] = j;
    }
}
if(arr[0] > arr[1] && arr[0] > arr[2]) cout << states[0] << endl;
else if(arr[1] > arr[1] && arr[1] > arr[2]) cout << states[1] << endl;
else if(arr[2] > arr[0] && arr[2] > arr[1]) cout << states[2] << endl;

return 0;
```

}